# Using an exported variable from another Meteor package

Tags: meteor

I'm trying to wrap an extension for Chart.js in a package for Meteor. Inside the extension, the author tries to access the global Chart variable.

Is exposing the variable like this in an export.js file (loaded before the extension) considered a proper solution?

```
this.Chart = Package['chart:chart'].Chart;
```